# Equivalent of Visual Studio's Watch Window in GUD

Tags: visual-studio, emacs, gud

I am using Emacs 23 to do some C development, with GUD (using GDB) as my debugger.

I have looked online, but haven't yet found an equivalent to Visual Studio's Watch Window in GUD. Essentially, this window lets you insert a list of expressions, which are evaluated each time the program is stepped, and shows you their value. Is there a similar feature to this in GUD?

I have seen that GDB has a feature called watch points, but that is not what I'm looking for.

Comment: Does `command` described here: https://blogs.oracle.com/ksplice/entry/8_gdb_tricks_you_should do what you want?

Answer (score 0):

Probably not a complete answer to what you want, but this might help wrt the Lisp debugger: Use `e` to evaluate a Lisp sexp that you enter. This can be as complex as you like. In particular, it can be a sexp that uses, say, `pp-eval-expression` to show, in another window, a complex return value from evaluating a sexp. Naturally, you can have a single sexp evaluate multiple sexps.

Having done this once, just use `e` with `M-p` to repeat it anytime during debugging, to get the updated evaluations of the sexps. You can also select the sexp as the *secondary selection*, and they use `M-mouse-2` to retrieve it for `e` at any time.